# Simplifying the algebraic

Tags: calculus

[image]

I don't know how we get $x+\frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{5}{24}x^4+....$ as the final answer

- my main problem is how that above mammoth expression is simplified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have the following:

$$\sin t=t-\frac{t^3}{6}+\frac{t^5}{120}-...$$
$$t=x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+...$$

The key thing to realize here is that in order to find the first fourth-degree approximation of $\sin t$, we don't care about any terms beyond $x^4$. Since $t$ is a multiple of $x$, all of the $t^5$ and $t^7$ and beyond terms will only contain terms of $x^5$ or greater, so we can ignore any terms beyond that. Thus, we get the following:

$$\sin t=t-\frac{t^3}{6}+\text{STUFF WE DON'T CARE ABOUT}$$

This helps us simplify things so we don't get too overwhelmed. Now, we need to plug in the very big series for $t$ into the above:

$$\sin(e^x-1)=\left(x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+...\right)-\frac{1}{6}\left(x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+...\right)^3+...$$

Cubing a series like this is pretty difficult. However, the first term is $x$, so let's express it as $(x+f(x))^3$ where $f(x)$ is the rest of the terms. Thus, we get:

$$(x+f(x))^3=x^3+3x^2f(x)+3xf^2(x)+f^3(x)$$

Now, $f(x)$ only contains terms of $x^2$ or higher, so it is a multiple of $x^2$. This means $f^2(x)$ is a multiple of $x^4$ and $xf^2(x)$ is a multiple of $x^5$. Also, $f^3(x)$ is a multiple of $x^6$. Both of these terms are too high a degree for us to care about, so we get the following:

$$(x+f(x))^3=x^3+3x^2f(x)+\text{STUFF WE DON'T CARE ABOUT}$$

Finally, let's actually plug in what $f(x)$ is:

$$\left(x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+...\right)^3=x^3+3x^2\left(\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+...\right)+\text...$$

Now, $x^2$ times $x^3$ is $x^5$, which, again, is too big for us to care. This means any terms beyond $x^2$ in $f(x)$ are basically useless to us, so we get:

$$\left(x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+...\right)^3=x^3+3x^2\left(\frac{x^2}{2}+\text{STUFF WE DON'T CARE ABOUT}\right)+\text... \\ =x^3+\frac{3x^4}{2}+\text{STUFF WE DON'T CARE ABOUT}$$

Now that we're done cubing this really long series, we can plug back into the equation for $\sin(e^x-1)$:

$$\sin(e^x-1)=\left(x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+...\right)-\frac{1}{6}\left(x^3+\frac{3x^4}{2}+...\right)+...$$

Distribute the $-\frac{1}{6}$:

$$\sin(e^x-1)=x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+...-\frac{x^3}{6}-\frac{x^4}{4}+...$$

Add like terms:

$$\sin(e^x-1)=x+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{5x^4}{24}+...$$

And, finally, we are done!

Comment: Wait, can I actually write "Things we do not care about"  in formal proofs???

Comment: @Raptor No, in formal proofs, you would just use ellipses like $...$ However, I used "STUFF WE DON'T CARE ABOUT" in order to make it really clear why we are throwing out these terms. Also, in a formal proof, I feel like you would find the terms of Taylor series using the $n^{\text{th}}$ derivatives of $\sin(e^x-1)$, not by manipulating infinite series.

Comment: The manipulation seems fairly legit though? Is it because of Reimann Series Theorem?

Comment: @Raptor It is definitely legitimate, but I think in a formal proof, it would be easier to use the $n^{\text{th}}$ derivative since that is more straightforward and easier to explain. However, manipulating infinite series like I did above definitely works, as long as you are careful and do not make mistakes.

Comment: Sir,  it would be very helpful if you explain how that mammoth expression generated from $sin(e^x-1)=sint=t-\frac{t^3}{3!}+\fract{t^5}{5!}-..........$

Comment: @Akash I am a bit confused as to what you mean. The first equation in my answer is just the Taylor series for $\sin t$ and the second equation is just the Taylor series for $t(x)=e^x-1$. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Thank you...i got my answer

Answer (score 1):

The previous step is  $$\sin (e^x-1)=\Bigg(x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+\cdots\Bigg)-\frac{1}{6}\Bigg[x^3+3x^2\Bigg(\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\cdots\Bigg)\Bigg]+\cdots$$

Add corresponding terms to get $$\sin(e^x-1)=x+\frac{x^2}{2}+0+\Bigg(\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{3x^4}{12}\Bigg)+\cdots=x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\Bigg(\frac{-5x^4}{24}\Bigg)+\cdots$$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want the Taylor expansion up to degree $4$, you can discard all terms containing $x^k$, with $k\ge5$ that can be summarized with $o(x^4)$.

Then, since
\begin{align}
e^x-1&=x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+o(x^4) \\[6px]
\sin y&=y-\frac{1}{6}y^3+o(y^4)
\end{align}
we can write
\begin{align}
\sin(e^x-1)=x&
+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+o(x^4) \\
&-\frac{1}{6}\left(x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+o(x^4)\right)^{\!3}\\
&+o(x^4)
\end{align}
This is less *mammoth* than what you have, isn't it?

Now we just need to compute the cube.

It's simpler if we write it as
$$
\left(x+\left(\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+o(x^4)\right)\right)^{\!3}
=\begin{aligned}[t]
x^3&+3x^2\left(\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+o(x^4)\right)\\
&+3x\left(\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+o(x^4)\right)^{\!2}\\
&+\left(\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+o(x^4)\right)^{\!3}
\end{aligned}
$$
Since we can gather all terms with degree $5$ or more in $o(x^4)$, the above simplifies into
$$
x^3+\frac{3x^4}{2}+o(x^4)
$$
and therefore
$$
\sin(e^x-1)=x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{x^3}{6}-\frac{x^4}{4}
+o(x^4)=x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{5x^4}{24}+o(x^4)
$$